# How to split many to many tables to achieve loosely coupled Microservice

Tags: database, api, rest, microservices, erd

I have three tables Invoice(InvoiceId, Invoicetotoalprice), table complaint(complaintId), and table are complaintType(complaintTypeID). And I have two microservices invoice Management and Complaint Management. So the table complaintType is identified by complaint table and invoice table; invoice Management and Complaint Management share the table the pic included to show the relation. Is there a pattern to deal with this problem? Also Microservice communication would be via API gateway
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlE2N.png)

Comment: Can you explain the many to many relation of complaintType table? which other two tables it relate?, in addition to this what is the relation between the order table and the invoice or complaint microservice, it is not very clear in the diagram

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to solve this kind of problem.
The first and easier to implement is to keep the table in one of the microservices, in your case I suppose that makes more sense to maintain it in complaint service, and in invoice service keep only the id of the table so if at any moment you need to request info of the complaint you have to make a request to the complaint service passing the id.

The second option and the best, because this way you minimize the communication between services and makes them less coupled, is to replicate the table so it will be two different tables in search microservice, but only one of the microservices will be the owner, in this case, I suppose will be the complaint microservice. So when any modification occurs in that table the complaint microservice will publish a message using some message broker like kafka and invoice service will consume it and update the table so there won't be inconsistencies between the two models. This way you decouple the two services and if for example, the complaint server goes down, it won't affect the invoice service

Comment: It seems in microservice it is not possible to achieve third normal form or would have to duplicate data. Then that would mean using microservice I would have to use NoSQL, right?